# Unable to find instrumentation target package: com.android.cts.stub

Tags: android, cts

Running the Android CTS encountering lot of failures due to following error :

```
Unable to find instrumentation target package: com.android.cts.stub
```

What might cause this error and how could i fix it? Note that there do have same test packages pass.

Answer (score 2):

With sufficient internal memory (data memoyry 801MB) on running the `android.permission` cts test case getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: com.android.cts.stub
```

If I push the `CtsTestStubs.apk` then above error doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

This might happed because of insufficient internal memory. Package "Cts TestCases" (CtsTestStubs.apk) should get installed successfully (check Manage Applications menu) while running CTS.